# MongoDB Java Driver won't connect to Replica Set or Secondary Server

Tags: java, mongodb, reactive-streams

I have a MongoDB replica set running on Docker.

When I try to connect to it no exception is thrown, but when I try to perform any operation to get or insert data, the Java driver hangs indefinitely. I am using the following code:

```
MongoClientSettings settings = MongoClientSettings.builder()
            .applyConnectionString(new ConnectionString("mongodb://" + IP)).build();
client = MongoClients.create(settings);
```

My IP is in this format `192.168.80.13:27017,192.168.80.12:27017`

I believe it is due to the secondary server, because I can connect to the primary on its own, but not the secondary. I have tried switching the primary and secondary and the same thing happens, so it's not a server problem.

I have also tried setting the read preference to secondary preferred with no avail. I am using the most recent version of the Reactive Streams Mongo Driver

Any ideas?

Comment: You need to include replicaSet in your connection string.

Comment: @simagix I tried with and without, with the same result.